# How to write String in ssl.conf file after a particular block of String?

Tags: linux

I want to write below line of code inside "ssl.conf" file only after the line which contains 
"# Allow DELETE for V2 APIs" .

Code want to insert : "RewriteRule          ^/batch$ /sim/afw/rest/batch [PT]"

Expected output should be :

## Allow DELETE for V2 APIs

RewriteRule          ^/batch$ /sim/afw/rest/batch [PT]

I am using macOS to connect to Linux box.

I used below commands ,but got no success .

sed '/Allow DELETE for V2 APIs/ i RewriteRule         ^/batch$ /sim/afw/rest/batch [PT]' ssl.conf

sed -i "/'Allow DELETE for V2 APIs'/a 'RewriteRule         ^/batch$ /sim/afw/rest/batch [PT]'" ssl.conf

I used ECHO to write data and i was successful .But i need pattern matcher then if it matches i want to insert the above line .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution :

sed -i ’s/^    # Allow DELETE for V2 APIs.*/    # Allow DELETE for V2 APIs\nRewriteRule         ^/batch$ /sim/afw/rest/batch [PT]/g’ ssl.conf

Here 's is used for searching the String .Then 2nd forward slash "/" is used for the condition to implement .As if the search string is found then replace that with all the character after forward slash . also for URLs we have to Escape using "\" .At last you have to give "/g" for Replacing the contents of the pattern space with the contents of the hold space. And last place file path along with the file name .If you are in same directory then only file name is enough .